# Proguard with Neo4j java.lang.VerifyError: Illegal type at constant pool entry 338 in class org.neo4j.cypher

Tags: java, neo4j, proguard

I'm trying to strip comments and variable names in a java project while leaving every other included library intact, the project is a single fat jar with all dependencies inside it.

I keep everything outside my package as is with a negation such as the following:

```
-keep class !com.myclasses.** { *; } #keep everything outside this package
```

so everything outside com.myclasses is kept as is.

I keep getting nasty errors such as the following however:

```
2017-03-13 15:03:45.354 [ERROR] AWT-EventQueue-0 (?) - Error  java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.VerifyError: Illegal type at constant pool entry 338 in class org.neo4j.cypher.internal.spi.v3_0.TransactionBoundQueryContext
Exception Details:
  Location:
    org/neo4j/cypher/internal/spi/v3_0/TransactionBoundQueryContext.createRelationship(Lorg/neo4j/graphdb/Node;Lorg/neo4j/graphdb/Node;Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/neo4j/graphdb/Relationship; @3: invokestatic
  Reason:
    Constant pool index 338 is invalid
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 2b2c 2db8 0152 b901 4e03 00b0          

    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at javax.swing.SwingWorker.get(SwingWorker.java:602)
    at com.myclasses.z$5.done(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.SwingWorker$5.run(SwingWorker.java:737)
    at javax.swing.SwingWorker.doneEDT(SwingWorker.java:741)
    at javax.swing.SwingWorker.access$100(SwingWorker.java:225)
    at javax.swing.SwingWorker$2.done(SwingWorker.java:302)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:384)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:251)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
    at javax.swing.SwingWorker.run(SwingWorker.java:334)
    at com.myclasses.z.b(Unknown Source)
    at com.myclasses.z$1.propertyChange(Unknown Source)
    at com.jgoodies.binding.beans.ExtendedPropertyChangeSupport.fireUnchecked(Unknown Source)
    at com.jgoodies.binding.beans.ExtendedPropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange0(Unknown Source)
    at com.jgoodies.binding.beans.ExtendedPropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(Unknown Source)
    at com.jgoodies.binding.beans.Model.firePropertyChange(Unknown Source)
    at com.jgoodies.binding.PresentationModel.access$300(Unknown Source)
    at com.jgoodies.binding.PresentationModel$BeanChangeHandler.propertyChange(Unknown Source)
    at com.jgoodies.binding.beans.ExtendedPropertyChangeSupport.fireUnchecked(Unknown Source)
    at com.jgoodies.binding.beans.ExtendedPropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange0(Unknown Source)
    at com.jgoodies.binding.beans.ExtendedPropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(Unknown Source)
    at com.jgoodies.binding.beans.Model.firePropertyChange(Unknown Source)
    at com.jgoodies.binding.beans.BeanAdapter.setBean0(Unknown Source)
    at com.jgoodies.binding.beans.BeanAdapter.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at com.jgoodies.binding.beans.BeanAdapter$BeanChangeHandler.propertyChange(Unknown Source)
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeListenerProxy.propertyChange(PropertyChangeListenerProxy.java:70)
    at com.jgoodies.binding.beans.ExtendedPropertyChangeSupport.fireUnchecked(Unknown Source)
    at com.jgoodies.binding.beans.ExtendedPropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange0(Unknown Source)
    at com.jgoodies.binding.beans.ExtendedPropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(Unknown Source)
    at com.jgoodies.binding.beans.Model.firePropertyChange(Unknown Source)
    at com.jgoodies.binding.value.AbstractValueModel.fireValueChange(Unknown Source)
    at com.jgoodies.binding.value.ValueHolder.setValue(Unknown Source)
    at com.jgoodies.binding.value.ValueHolder.setValue(Unknown Source)
    at com.jgoodies.binding.PresentationModel.setBean(Unknown Source)
    at com.myclasses.b$1.valueChanged(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JList.fireSelectionValueChanged(JList.java:1796)
    at javax.swing.JList$ListSelectionHandler.valueChanged(JList.java:1810)
    at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:184)
    at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:154)
    at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.setValueIsAdjusting(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:685)
    at javax.swing.JList.setValueIsAdjusting(JList.java:2140)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicListUI.java:2796)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:290)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:289)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6535)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6300)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Illegal type at constant pool entry 338 in class org.neo4j.cypher.internal.spi.v3_0.TransactionBoundQueryContext
Exception Details:
  Location:
    org/neo4j/cypher/internal/spi/v3_0/TransactionBoundQueryContext.createRelationship(Lorg/neo4j/graphdb/Node;Lorg/neo4j/graphdb/Node;Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/neo4j/graphdb/Relationship; @3: invokestatic
  Reason:
    Constant pool index 338 is invalid
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 2b2c 2db8 0152 b901 4e03 00b0          

    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.CompatibilityFor3_0$ExecutionPlanWrapper.org$neo4j$cypher$internal$compatibility$CompatibilityFor3_0$ExecutionPlanWrapper$$queryContext(Unknown Source)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.CompatibilityFor3_0$ExecutionPlanWrapper$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.CompatibilityFor3_0$ExecutionPlanWrapper$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.exceptionHandlerFor3_0$.runSafely(Unknown Source)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.CompatibilityFor3_0$ExecutionPlanWrapper.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.PreparedPlanExecution.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.ExecutionEngine.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.javacompat.ExecutionEngine.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.ClassicCoreSPI.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacade.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacade.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.myclasses.z$a.b(Unknown Source)
    at com.myclasses.z$a.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.myclasses.z$a.doInBackground(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.SwingWorker$1.call(SwingWorker.java:295)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    ... 66 more
```